# $i18n Locale get changed when navigating

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, nuxt.js

I use Nuxt $i18n for multi language website ,
I change the default language and as I navigate between pages , the selected language get change to default language ?
this is $i18n config in nuxt config
why is that ?

```js
i18n: {
  locales: [
    { code: 'en', iso: 'en-US', dir: 'ltr' },
    { code: 'de', iso: 'de-GER', dir: 'ltr' }
  ],
  defaultLocale: 'de',
  vueI18n: {
    fallbackLocale: 'de',
    messages: {
      en: en.messages,
      de: de.messages
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: How to do navigate, `<nuxt-link>` or `<a>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally i got **this is answer** :

```html
<nuxt-link :to="localePath('/home')"> home </nuxt-link>
```

Answer (score 1):

For create route path use

```
method this.localePath(...), ctx.app.localePath(...)
```

only this method prepare path with current locale or you can do this himself

Answer (score 0):

For people who are dealing with this in nuxt3 with locale cookie, try

```js
<script setup>
const localeRoute = useLocaleRoute()
const { locale } = useI18n()
const linkPath = computed(() => {
  const route = localeRoute('blog', locale.value)
  return route != null ? route.path : '/'
})
</script>

<template>
  <NuxtLink :to="linkPath">{{ $t('blog') }}</NuxtLink>
</template>
```

found in https://v8.i18n.nuxtjs.org/api/composables